# Hibernate. big Results and Pagination

Tags: java, hibernate

atm I'm fetchin a small amount of data (round a bout 100 records) as list and let displaytag render a table for this data. Now I'm facing a problem: I'm in need to show more results at once. If the query results in a size of > 5000 objects everything slows extremly down.

I was wondering if there are any best-practices to recieve such big collections and forward them to the view layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article explains paging results: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t63849.html

Basically you will get results a handful at a time (you decide how much).  After you get those results you go back for more when you want them using hibernates query.setFirstResult(startingIndex) and query.setMaxResults(howMuch).

I also did something in java that probably isn't a great solution but it works.  I have my controller method that does the hibernate work pass back a SwingWorker that executes some code  to load the data.  This way it happens in the background and the UI is loading normally.

Paging seems to be the best solution though.